# How can I give a user permission to open low port numbers?

Tags: kernel

If I'm root, how can I give a user permission to open low port numbers ? Or how can I take away the right to open high port numbers from a user?

Answer (score 5):

You can allow specific programs (not users) to open privileged ports:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/executable
```

As for restricting access to certain ports, see [Allow/Deny a user from binding a range of ports](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59297/allow-deny-a-user-from-binding-a-range-of-ports).